How can i get the cost of a resource in Azure for any period?
I am trying to get the cost of a resource , app service in Azure for a period of time . I use the following
 az consumption usage list --query "[?contains(properties.instanceName, '<my resourrce    name>')].properties.usageAmount" --output table

But it does not return anything . Gives error
 ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api     version after 2019-10-01


What is the resource you are trying to retrieve? @Jenny


ERROR: (400) Subscription scope usage is not supported for current Api version. Please use Api version after 2019-10-01:

The above error says that the Api version you are using is an older version and you need to use a latest Api version which is 2023-11-01 as given in the MSDoc.
And also az consumption usage command is under preview and development. So as an alternative workaround, use az rest method to invoke the cost management details and retrieve it as shown below.
az rest --method get --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subid/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2023-11-01" --query "value[?contains(properties.instanceName, 'apsbjah')].properties.usageAmount" --output table


You can also use a rest API to get all the usage details of the Azure management group with the URL:
https://management.azure.com/<Resource ID>/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2023-11-01


I ran the first command I get nothing back ? The second for a resource , it says the resource has been moved and i know it there cause i browse to it ?

Should it be https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/ or https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/ ?

ok now i can get the details , was a timeout issue .   Which values are used to calculate the usage ? Is it quantity * amount ?
